# How to use pagination in class-based generic views?

Tags: python, django, django-generic-views, django-pagination

I try to implement pagination to class-based generic view and in way I did it, it's not works.

urls

```
url(r'^cat/(?P<category>[\w+\s]*)/page(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$',
    CategorizedPostsView.as_view(), {'paginate_by': 3}),
```

view

```
class CategorizedPostsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'categorizedposts.djhtml'
    context_object_name = 'post_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        cat = unquote(self.kwargs['category'])
        category = get_object_or_404(ParentCategory, category=cat)
        return category.postpages_set.all()
```

template

```
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if post_list.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ post_list.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ post_list.number }} of {{ post_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if post_list.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ post_list.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

When I try to get the http:// 127.0.0.1:8000/cat/category_name/?page=1 or even http:// 127.0.0.1:8000/cat/category_name/ I got 404 exception.

How to use pagination in class-based generic views in right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hey there is already a kwarg `paginate_by` for the `ListView` so just pass it in.
try something like this:

```
url(r'^cat/(?P<category>[\w+\s]*)/page(?P<page>[0-9]+)/$',
    CategorizedPostsView.as_view(paginate_by=3)),
```

and for your template you could try something like:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}

            <span class="current">
                Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>

            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks. And URL will be a little simpler - `url(r'^cat/(?P<category>[\w+\s]*)/$, CategorizedPostsView.as_view(paginate_by=3)),` 
For get method explicit declaration of url is not necessary.